# Get the value of a dynamically added radio button (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to get the value of the dynamically generated radio button when this button is selected.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<div id="divContainer">
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#divContainer").on("change", $('input[name="name1"]:checked'), function () {
            var selectedVal=$('input[name="name1"]:checked').val();
            console.log(selectedVal);
    });
```

The value of the selectedVal is returning null here.

---

#### Resolution:

The default value was not properly assigned. I updated my code snippet which generates the radio button:

```
('#radiBtn').attr("value",val);
```

This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $ wrapping from selector `just use 'input[name="name1"]:checked'`t
 for getting changed object use `this`

```js
var div = $("#divContainer").on("change", 'input[name="name1"]:checked', function() {
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  console.log(selectedVal);
});

$('<input>', {
  name: 'name1',
  type: 'radio',
  value: 1
}).appendTo(div);

$('<input>', {
  name: 'name1',
  type: 'radio',
  value: 2
}).appendTo(div);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divContainer">
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work. this-> refers to the divContainer here.

Comment: @pcs : nope , this refers to radio button not div

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. I believe the radio buttons here are appended to the <div>tag whereas in my code snippet I'm adding it inside the <div> tag.

Comment: me also appending the radio  button inside div tag.... dynamically after binding the event handler..